# the significance of fifth dimension blackholes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes

is there a significance of *fifth dimension black holes* in theoretical and experimental physics?
the concept of the fifth dimension is really hard to wrap my head around and i do not see how these objects have an importance in the study of physics

Comment: What is the fifth dimension supposed to be?

Comment: in reference to this publication : [The Black Hole at the Birth of the Universe](https://www.perimeterinstitute.ca/news/black-hole-birth-universe) ? A piece to add to the story of astronomia research ...

Comment: @igael: When theoretical physicists have trouble dealing with 3+1 dimensional reality mathematically (it is one of the most complex cases,it seems), they often expand their exploration into higher dimensions. Physics in higher dimensions is more boring (distance decouples systems) and hence the math is often easier. The three dimensional Kepler problem, for instance, can be reduced to the four dimensional harmonic oscillator. As part of the learning curve this is perfectly OK... but too often what starts out as a mathematical act of desperation becomes a statement of fact in press releases.

Comment: @CuriousOne Publications ( like the answers on p.s.e ) use the present tense and the verb to be to explain that stuff. Just think to people which beleive that it's all joke. Carreers... A great university president told me that most universitary scientists must stop and try to do something else ... but all aren't able to.

Comment: @igael: It's like with inventions... 1000 go into the garbage before one turns into a success. Science is no different. We need a thousand good busywork scientists to enable one lucky (also good one) to succeed big. There is nothing wrong with all of these inquiries. What I am critical about is the interface to the public. Instead of explaining what we are really doing and why it can't be done any other way, many institutions and even individuals have given in to exaggeration about the consequences of research. The public is not completely without responsibility... they ache for sensation.

Comment: Suggestion to the post (v1): Replace the phrase _fifth dimension black holes_ with _five dimensional black holes._